# Returning the number of entries in comma separated cell that are matched against an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have contents of a cell which are comma separated with each cell containing variable number of entries. The cell contents are not unique.

E.g.

Cell 1
item@domain1, item@domain2, item@domain3, item@domain1, item@domain1, item@domain2, item@domain20

Cell 2
item@domain15, item@domain2, item@domain1, item@domain3, item@domain4, item@domain4

I want to compare the contents of each cell against a RANGE of values and determine how many times there is a match.

If the RANGE to compare against was

domain1
domain2
domain3

then the result for Cell 1 and Cell 2 would be 6 and 3 respectively.

Fingers crossed this is possible in an array formula format...

Thanks in advance for anyone taking the time to read this and hopefully come up with a nice solution :0)

Comment: I think you'll need vba to do this. (Use the vba.Split function, amongst others). Consider tagging vba?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I added the excel-vba tag on your suggestion.

Comment: Like Bathsheba said in VBA it's easy using the split function to return a range and then you can just use countif to count the number of occurences. A non VBA solution would be to extract the list to multiple columns. Data -> Text to Columns -> Delimited etc.

Comment: The problem I think I have with the text to columns approach is the variable number of comma separated entries in each cell.

You mention the VBA solution is easy. Only if you know how, which I don't :0)

Solution suggestions more than welcomed...

Comment: Are the list of matches in some cells as well??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution to count the number of matches between two list and output a message box with the result.

My data looks like this:

[image]

Code:

```
Sub compareListA()
    Dim listA As String
    Dim compareList As Variant
    Dim compareSplit As Variant
    Dim count As Integer

    listA = [A1]
    compareList = Split(listA, ",")

    compareSplit = Split([A5], ",")

    count = 0
    For idx = LBound(compareSplit) To UBound(compareSplit)
        If InStr(listA, Trim(compareSplit(idx))) Then
            For j = LBound(compareList) To UBound(compareList)
                If Trim(compareList(j)) = Trim(compareSplit(idx)) Then
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next idx

    MsgBox (count & " Matches Found Between List")
End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

---

**Function Solution:**

You can change this to a cell function in which you pass in your two list like this:

In cell `C1` enter this formula: `=compareMyList(A2,$G$2)`

Code:

```
Function compareMyList(rngA As Range, rngCompare As Range)
    Dim listA As String
    Dim compareList As Variant
    Dim compareSplit As Variant
    Dim count As Integer

    listA = [rngA]
    compareList = Split([rngA], ",")

    compareSplit = Split([rngCompare], ",")

    count = 0
    For idx = LBound(compareSplit) To UBound(compareSplit)
        If InStr(listA, Trim(compareSplit(idx))) Then
            For j = LBound(compareList) To UBound(compareList)
                If Trim(compareList(j)) = Trim(compareSplit(idx)) Then
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next idx

    compareMyList = count
End Function
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, moving me in the right direction. I am a total VBA noob so forgive me if I ask too much...

How can the VBA be extended to read multiple cell entries in a column and output the hit number in the next column per cell contents compared? I about 15000 column entries to compare against a list of static values. (I hope that makes sense...)

Comment: I added a function option, now you can use an in-cell formula and pass in the two list you want to compare.  Once you have your format setup correctly you can drag the formula down but this depends on your implementation.

Comment: This looks to be on the money. Let me knock it up into Excel (a task in itself) and I will mark it as accepted if it does the trick.

Comment: Thanks! I got it in excel but never get the right value. I assume you found the same bug...

Quick question, my list of things to compare isn't comma separated, it is a range. Could you accommodate this?

Comment: I corrected the code, I made a gross assumption and had to rework it.  Copy the new code over (latest revision).  This should account for different possible errors.

Comment: Your question is actually much simpler if we are dealing with a range instead of a list inside a single cell.  BTW: Your question specifically states "Cell 1 contains..."  You can probably use array formulas if your list are in separate cells.  Either update your question with examples or accept this solution and post a new question.  Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, for the ambiguous wording. My bad. I have since corrected to be accurate. I hope this makes it easier to suggest a solution.